# How to handle NullpointerException in this case

Tags: java

This is my for loop function inside the servlet

Here i have a question .
The Data will be passed from the USER Interface to this .

In some conditions , some information (For example  symbol or side ) may not be passed , then in those conditions , i am getting NullPointreException as null would be supplied to it .

```
List<Bag> bags = new ArrayList<Bag>(bagdata.length);

for (FormBeanData ld : data) {
    Bag bag = new Bag();
    bag.symbol = ld.getSymbol();
    bag.side = ld.getSide();
    bags.add(bag );
}
```

Is there anyway we can handle such situations ??

Thank you .

Comment: as @Matteo suggested bellow, you may want to put some default values if those objects are null.

Comment: it would useful if you could post the code you are executing and the actual error (where does it occur).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you submitted most likely does not even compile: `bags.add(Bag)` does not make sense. You need to add the `bag` object (the instance), not `Bag` (the class).

In any case if you want to check if a reference is `null` just check it:

```
if (myobject != null) {
    myobject.myfield = ... // myobject is not null
} else {
    // ignore, print an error, do what is required to do
}
```

You also have to check before iterating

```
if (collection != null) {
  for (Object o : collection) {
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Just check if any of the values is equal to null

```
List bags = new ArrayList(bagdata.length);
for (FormBeanData ld : data) {
    if(ld!=null && ld.getSymbol()!=null && ld.getSide()!=null) {
        Bag bag = new Bag();
        bag.symbol = ld.getSymbol();
        bag.side = ld.getSide();
        bags.add(Bag);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not where he probably has the exception: if `ld.getSymbol()` is `null` then `bag.symbol = ld.getSymbol` will **not** generate an exception. It will just assign `null`. Most likely `data` is null but the code Revathi submitted cannot be correct (see add(Bag)) so is difficult to see where the exception is occurring. Your code will also crash if data is null.